# Could someone clarify unset($row['something'])?

Tags: php, unset

I would like to have this peace of code clarified:

```
unset($row['something']);
```

Because in my code, I use this to delete a number of columns from my results that I get from a query. I'm using this to get the array and walk through it:

```
$rows = array();
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
```

I need the columns to make other combined columns. Later when I try to do an export to csv file it is still showing the unset columns. Which should have been deleted using unset. So in the while I use the unset method to delete a couple of columns.

Really hope someone can help me with this because I don't know how to delete these columns from my array.

**UPDATE:**

```
public function getRows()
{
    global $global_db_link;
    $result = $global_db_link->query($this->getQuery());

    $rows = array();
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
    {
    // This is where i use different columns to calculate something 
    // and make a new column out of it
        unset($row['column_header']);       
        $rows[] = $row;
    }
return $rows;
```

So this is it in a short version.

Comment: Can you show us where you are calling the unset method?

Comment: `unset` should work as expected, unless `column_header` does not exist; may be a spelling mistake or unnecessary white space in the key. Do a `var_dump($row)` before unset and make sure you are unsetting the correct column.

Comment: Where does var_dump go. I googled it just now but can't really see where it goes

Comment: It will show you exactly what `$row` contains and you will be able to debug your code.

Comment: If I add that code line var_dump($row) my code will stop working

Answer (score 0):

Unset can be used to remove information from am array of information, as you say above. However `$row` in your while loop is fetching information from your database. Why would you ever need to unset specific rows? I'm not even sure if that is possible.

You would be better off building a second array that excludes the specified columns for your export to CSV.

Comment: I need to use the specific rows to create other combined rows(which is said in my question). But what i can do is put the unset methods in the next array. Maybe this will help if what you are saying is true. EDIT: This doesn't work.

Comment: @user3398922 after using those specific rows, why don't you craete another array with only the columns you need?

Comment: I have a way of doing that in another answer but it doesn't seem to be working. Do you have another way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that you select a set of columns from the database, compute some new columns based on the selected ones, and you want to export a list of columns (some selected, some computed) to CSV.

I suggest you do it like this:

```
public function getRows()
{
    global $global_db_link;
    $result = $global_db_link->query($this->getQuery());

    $rows = array();
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
    {
    // This is where i use different columns to calculate something 
    // and make a new column out of it
        //unset($row['column_header']);      
        // I assume that you add computed elements to row, like:
        $row['computed1'] = $row['selected1'] + $row['selected2'];        
        $rows[] = array($row['computed1'],$row['selected3'],$row['selected4'],$row['computed2']);
    }
return $rows;
```

This means that you will create an array with a combination of computed / selected columns that you want to export to CSV, and not worry about unsetting anything.

Comment: I tried this but it doesn't work. I'm still getting the unnecessary columns.

Comment: Are you sure you have tried this ? You said: $rows[] = $row; and I've said $rows[] = array($row['computed1'],$row['selected3'],$row['selected4'],$row['computed2']); this way you will say exactly what columns you need (you only put here the columns that you want to return)

Comment: I have this exact same code. My problem now is that the data is okay. It doesn't show in my html table and the titles aren't there in my csv export

Comment: For titles, you should do someting like:  $rows[] = array('Title1','Title2','Title3','Title4'); before the first call of getRows. For showing in HTML table, you have to share the code that you use to generate HTML.